# How can I make a key press trigger movement of an image in cocos2d (python)?

Tags: python, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on the following program, based on some [introductory lessons](http://python.cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/quickstart.html) in the cocos2d programming guide (for 2d game design).

The program has two classes, HelloWorld and KeyDisplay.

HelloWorld displays the image of a bird and the phrase "Get this bird some pizza!".  The phrase is enlarged and shrunken every 2 seconds using `cocos.actions.ScaleBy` and `cocos.actions.Reverse`.  It works great.

KeyDisplay takes a user keyboard input and writes the character on the screen using an on_key_press function.  It is also working properly.

Next I would like to modify things going on in HelloWorld through KeyDisplay.  For example, I would like to change the scale of the image (`sprite.scale`) or change the position of the image (`sprite.position`).  This requires the HelloWorld and KeyDisplay class objects to talk to one another.

Unfortunately, KeyDisplay class does not know about the HelloWorld class, and thus the variables are inaccessible.  For example, if I try to set sprite.scale = 0.5 in the `on_key_press` function I get an error.

Is there a way for KeyDisplay to respond to keypress events, modifying sprites and other variables in my HelloWorld class?  I guess this is both a python programming question and a cocos2d game design question.  Generally I have needed to create the sprite and label inside of the HelloWorld class (in the `__init__(self)` method).  I haven't been allowed to create the sprite or label globally so far.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
import cocos
import pyglet
# note: needed to change something in the operating system before importing cocos, running this command:
# defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO



class HelloWorld(cocos.layer.ColorLayer):
    def __init__(self):
        super( HelloWorld, self ).__init__( 64,64,224,255)
        self.world_width = 1000
        self.world_height = 1000
        self.px_width = 1000
        self.px_height = 1000

        label = cocos.text.Label('Get this bird some pizza!',
                       font_name='Times New Roman',
                       font_size=32,
                       anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

        label.position = 320,100
        self.add( label )
        sprite = cocos.sprite.Sprite('bower-bird.jpeg')
        sprite.position = 320,320
        sprite.scale = 1
        self.add( sprite, z=1 )

        scale = cocos.actions.ScaleBy(3, duration=2)
        label.do( cocos.actions.Repeat( scale + cocos.actions.Reverse( scale) ) )
        #sprite.do( cocos.actions.Repeat( scale + cocos.actions.Reverse( scale) ) )


class KeyDisplay(cocos.layer.Layer):

    # If you want that your layer receives director.window events
    # you must set this variable to 'True'
    is_event_handler = True

    def __init__(self):

        super( KeyDisplay, self ).__init__()

        self.text = cocos.text.Label("", x=100, y=280 )

        # To keep track of which keys are pressed:
        self.keys_pressed = set()
        self.update_text()
        self.add(self.text)

    def update_text(self):
        key_names = [pyglet.window.key.symbol_string (k) for k in self.keys_pressed]
        text = 'Keys: '+','.join (key_names)
        # Update self.text
        self.text.element.text = text

    def on_key_press (self, key, modifiers):
        """This function is called when a key is pressed.
        'key' is a constant indicating which key was pressed.
        'modifiers' is a bitwise or of several constants indicating which
            modifiers are active at the time of the press (ctrl, shift, capslock, etc.)
        """
        self.keys_pressed.add (key)
        self.update_text()

    def on_key_release (self, key, modifiers):
        """This function is called when a key is released.

        'key' is a constant indicating which key was pressed.
        'modifiers' is a bitwise or of several constants indicating which
            modifiers are active at the time of the press (ctrl, shift, capslock, etc.)

        Constants are the ones from pyglet.window.key
        """

        self.keys_pressed.remove (key)
        self.update_text()

    def update_text(self):
        key_names = [pyglet.window.key.symbol_string (k) for k in self.keys_pressed]
        text = 'Keys: '+','.join (key_names)
        # Update self.text
        self.text.element.text = text

#start it up ... 

cocos.director.director.init()
hello_layer = HelloWorld ()
main_scene = cocos.scene.Scene (hello_layer, KeyDisplay())
cocos.director.director.run (main_scene)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from gituser: JPwright
basically create a Move class (the 'Me' class) then you invoke it in the 'do' function of your sprite. the 'step' function is essentially what is being "done"

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

import cocos
from cocos import actions, layer, sprite, scene
from cocos.director import director

# Player class

class Me(actions.Move):

  # step() is called every frame.
  # dt is the number of seconds elapsed since the last call.
  def step(self, dt):

    super(Me, self).step(dt) # Run step function on the parent class.

    # Determine velocity based on keyboard inputs.
    velocity_x = 100 * (keyboard[key.RIGHT] - keyboard[key.LEFT])
    velocity_y = 100 * (keyboard[key.UP] - keyboard[key.DOWN])

    # Set the object's velocity.
    self.target.velocity = (velocity_x, velocity_y)

# Main class

def main():
  global keyboard # Declare this as global so it can be accessed within class methods.

  # Initialize the window.
  director.init(width=500, height=300, autoscale=False, resizable=True)

  # Create a layer and add a sprite to it.
  player_layer = layer.Layer()
  me = sprite.Sprite('bower-bird.jpeg')
  player_layer.add(me)

  # Set initial position and velocity.
  me.position = (100, 100)
  me.velocity = (0, 0)

  # Set the sprite's movement class.
  me.do(Me())

  # Create a scene and set its initial layer.
  main_scene = scene.Scene(player_layer)

  # Attach a KeyStateHandler to the keyboard object.
  keyboard = key.KeyStateHandler()
  director.window.push_handlers(keyboard)

  # Play the scene in the window.
  director.run(main_scene)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```